# javascript variable equal to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
var iframe= "<iframe src='article_course.php?option="+option+"&userid="+userid+"&course="+course+"&article="+escape(article)'/>";
```

I'm doing something wrong in this declaration. Please help!

Comment: Well, it's not equal to an iframe, it's been assigned a string.

Comment: That's not an iframe. it's a string that happens to contain some html that would be an iframe if that text was embedded in a web page.

Comment: "Something wrong" is not very enlightening. What are you trying to do and what is the problem you're having?

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? You've posted one line of code; with no explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not terminating the string concatenation correctly:

```
...+escape(article)'/>";
```

Should be:

```
...+escape(article) + "/>";
```

Resulting in:

```
var iframe = "<iframe src='article_course.php?option="+option+"&userid="+userid+"&course="+course+"&article="+escape(article) +"/>";​​​​
```

Comment: +1 for understanding a bad question

Comment: +1 @Nathan for such a comment.